# Windows phone 8.1 rss reader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have to make an app for windows phone 8.1 which is going to be a WP app for existing web site. They gave me a rss feed so I have to make a WP ress feed reader. This will me my first WP 8.1 app and it seems I'm not doing well in this field. I tried  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487167%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) example from MSDN and I'm getting some crazy errors.

At this point "8. Set up the RssTextTrimmer class as a converter by double-clicking App.xaml in Solution Explorer, and then adding the following code inside the  tag ..." I'm getting this error "The name "RssTextTrimmer" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:InfoBA""

Here is my App.xml file

```
<Application
    x:Class="InfoBA.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:InfoBA">
    <Application.Resources>
        <converter:RssTextTrimmer xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:InfoBA" x:Key="RssTextTrimmer" />
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

So please, does anyone knows what could cause this error?

Comment: RSS is a simple xml. Have you tried to load it with `XDocument.Load(url)`

Comment: Just download the full project and compare.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/RSS-Reader-Sample-1702775f

Comment: I didn't tried XDocument.Load(url), but I downloaded full project and it works. I just needed to convert this project to WP8.1, install Silverlight SDK v4.0 and add System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll to my project. Thank you for the help